# How to re-order the GET parameters in an URL?

Tags: python, http, testing

I'm comparing two urls in a test and I want the equality test to pass even if the GET parameters or not in the same order:

- https://example.org/?kind=4&limit=10
- https://example.org/?limit=10&kind=4

Answer (score 0):

I made a [Pull Request to `niksite/url-normalize`](https://github.com/niksite/url-normalize/pull/7/).

```
>>> from url_normalize import url_normalize
>>> print(url_normalize('foo.com/?c=2&o=2&a=b'))
http://foo.com/?a=b&c=2&o=2
```

In general the solution seems to be [URL normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization), but Wikipedia has a warning for that:

> However, the order of parameters in a URL may be significant (this is not defined by the standard) and a web server may allow the same variable to appear multiple times.